# How to run different python multiprocesses with different user privileges

Tags: python, permissions, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, pyalsaaudio

I'm coding a RPi project in python that requires me to access microphones for speech_recognition, LEDs for rpi_ws281x, and control output volume with alsaaudio. The problem I'm having is that to access the microphone and LEDs, I have to run my code as admin (permission denied if not) but to have control over volume settings I can't be an admin (alsaaudio can't find Master mixer control or any mixer for that matter). Right now I have a multiprocess that sitting in the background that waits for volume change requests from the user and the speech recognition is running in another multiprocess.

Is there a way I can have the multiprocesses run with different privileges so that I don't have issues accessing either the microphone or volume settings? Or is it possible for me to change permissions so that I can access the microphone as a normal user?